# React Component Design

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react.js

Building out a React component that is supposed to hold the following information and display it in a feed-like page. The idea is to later map over the individual entries in an array.

- Author
- Timestamp
- Message Title
- Message body

Currently, I have the following code in one file (BuildingUpdateBox.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import "./BuildingUpdateBox.css"


const BuildingUpdateBoxHeader = (props) => {
const author = props.author ? `Author: ${props.author}` : 'No Author'
return (
  <div className="building-update-box-header">
    <span className="building-update-box-header-item">{author}</span>
    <span className="building-update-box-header-item">Timestamp: {props.timestamp}</span>
</div>
)
}

const BuildingUpdateBoxBody = (props) => {
return (
  <div className="building-update-box-body">
    <div className="building-update-box-body-title"><h2>{props.title}</h2></div>
    <div className="building-update-box-body-message"><p>{props.message}</p></div>
  </div>
)
}

const BuildingUpdateBox = (props) => {
return (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="building-update-box">
      <BuildingUpdateBoxHeader
        author={props.content.author}
        timestamp={props.content.timestamp}
      />
      <BuildingUpdateBoxBody
        title={props.content.title}
        message={props.content.message}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
)
}

export default BuildingUpdateBox;
```

And in App.js (I currently use create-react-app):

```
const message = {
  author: 'Joe Smith',
  timestamp: '2018/12/22',
  title: 'Broken Heater',
  message: 'Dear tenants, we will have a plumber onsite tomorrow, who will replace the broken boiler. We apologize for the inconvenience. If you have any questions, please feel free to reach out to 123-456-7890.'
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BuildingUpdateBox content={message} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm looking to hear if I should:

- Place the functional components into their own files (with reasoning)
- Even use 3 separate functions, since I don't ever see the Header or Body being used without the Box and vice versa
- Do anything with the way I import the CSS

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you want a more in depth review you should provide more code and a potential specifics you want to improve on; your code is very thin, and so it's a little difficult to help you expand on it, however, I would say that there's a few different things you can do to this to improve or follow a different direction forward.

Your use of pure components is good for `BuildingUpdateBoxHeader` and `BuildingUpdateBoxBody` as using primitive props is better for performance. However, using a `content` object inside your props for `BuildingUpdateBox` means React cannot shallow compare your props and is unable to determine when not to rerender the component, causing potentially wasted rerenders.

I would recommend trying JSS (css in js) to embed your styles directly in your application for an alternate solution to specifying `className` manually. This couples your css with its implementation rather than needing to update both the css & js when you modify them.